# Can SharePoint do subforms?

Tags: sharepoint, forms

I would like to create a form that manages opportunities for my business.

The form would collect all relevent information like order date, time, etc.

But, within this form, I would like to have 3 subforms:

1. One that collects Customer information and will be linked to a wider Customer Database
2. One that collects action items that will essentially be linked to a workflow that assigns people to actions
3. One that collects Guarantee information (basically, in some deals we would have multiple guarantees, and I'd like to have an option to "Add more")

For me, this would be solved by creating "sub-forms". Is there such a thing in SharePoint?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, with some digging, I found this resource:
Video 1 of 6: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO1lc_mEThc

This is a parent/child relationship video by Mark Rackley that I found incredibly useful in building a form with subforms. Hope this helps others :)